# Material UI List onClick fires click event on nested list

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, material-ui

I have a material ui list in my one of the component. When I click any item of this list, I go to another listView. I am using router to go to another listView. And using onClick method. Whenever I click any list item of first list I print  "firstList clicked". and whenever I click any item if second list, it print "secondList clicked".

Here is my Problem:
When I click the ListItem of first list, the console.log("secondList clicked") also gets printed with "firstList Clicked" automatically. I have four list items in second list, so my console print output looks like this

> firstList Clicked
>   secondList Clicked
>   secondList Clicked
>   secondList Clicked
>   secondList Clicked

Why is this happening?

Here is my code.

SecondList code

```
class TagListItemDetails extends Component {
    handleClick() {
        console.log("secondList clicked")
    }

    handleButtonClick() {
        browserHistory.push("TagList")
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <div>
                    <List id="parent-list-tags">
                        <ListItem primaryText="Kitchen" onTouchTap={this.handleClick()}/>
                        <ListItem primaryText="Beach" onClick={this.handleClick()}/>
                        <ListItem primaryText="Marriage" onClick={this.handleClick()}/>
                        <ListItem primaryText="Garden" onClick={this.handleClick()}/>
                    </List>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                    <div className="backButton">
                        <RaisedButton backgroundColor="#293C8E" label="Back" onClick={this.handleButtonClick} labelColor="white">

                        </RaisedButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps =(state) =>{
    return {
        tags: state.tagReducer
    };
};

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({tagSelected: tagSelected}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(TagListItemDetails);
```

firstList

```
export default class TagList extends Component {


    handleClicked() {
        console.log("firstList Clicked")
        browserHistory.push("TagListItemDetails")
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <List id="parent-list-tags" >
                    <ListItem primaryText="Scene" onClick={this.handleClicked}  />
                    <Divider/>
                    <ListItem primaryText="Actors" onClick={this.handleClicked} />
                    <Divider/>
                    <ListItem primaryText="Emotions" onClick={this.handleClicked} />
                    <Divider/>
                    <ListItem primaryText="Actions" onClick={this.handleClicked}/>
                    <Divider/>
                    <ListItem primaryText="Objects" onClick={this.handleClicked}/>
                    <Divider/>
                    <ListItem primaryText="Compliance" onClick={this.handleClicked} />
                </List>
                <AddButton />
            </div>

    )
    }
};
```

Comment: In the SecondList, you are invoking the handleClick method when the component is rendered. Try removing the parentheses `()`  from the onClick handler:  `onClick={this.handleClick}`

Comment: It worked. But what if I want to do something in secondList with my actions as props like this : onClick={this.props.itemSelected(2)} . where itemSelected being the action function and 2 is the parameter I pass it. I am talking about react-redux here.

Comment: As a quick fix, you should be able use a fat arrow function like so:  `onClick={() => this.props.itemSelected(2)}` Let me know if it works. Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/YGRQrG

Comment: And when I try to do onClick={this.props.itemSelected(2)}, it gave me this error : Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within  render or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to componentWillMount.

Comment: Do you get this error if you use `onClick={() => this.props.itemSelected(2)}`? You should not be using `onClick={this.props.itemSelected(2)}`.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked.

Comment: Glad it helped :) I've written up the above as an answer so that it is easier to refer to by the community.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is that in the `SecondList`, you are invoking the `handleClick` method as soon as the component is loaded. Try removing the parentheses `()` from the onClick handler. So instead of

```
<ListItem primaryText="Beach" onClick={this.handleClick()}/>
```

you can use:

```
<ListItem primaryText="Beach" onClick={this.handleClick}/>
------------------------------------------------------^^ No parentheses here
```

One way of passing arguments to a click handler passed as a prop is to use the fat arrow function:

```
onClick={() => this.props.itemSelected(2)}

// or if you want to pass the event as well: 

onClick={(event) => this.props.itemSelected(2, event)}
```

Also, here is a demo of how to fire two functions on `onClick` event : http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/YGRQrG

Comment: Does the above answer your question or would you like me to add anything?

Comment: I have one problem but. What should I do if I want to pass the both, the action as well as handleClickEvent method to my onClick. How should I do it?

Comment: You can pass the event like so: `<div onClick={(event) => this.props.onClick('Secret message', event)}>` Have a look at the updated codepen.

Comment: I want to fire two functions on onClick and not a message and event

Comment: No problem :) I've updated codepen with two functions fired onClick.

Comment: So I didn't understand it. Can you please write the exact code lines for my code to make it work. Would be a big help.

Comment: Please add a codepen or JSFiddle explaining the issue so that I can help you out. Otherwise we will be going in circles :)